# error in creation table

Tags: tables

i want create this table:
[image]

my code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
                \caption{Aceptaciones a usuarios intrusos} 
                \begin{center} % tabla centrada en el texto
                    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}%l -> left, c -> center, r -> right       
                    \hline  
                    \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Hiperparametros}}\\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{SVM} & {ANN} \\ \hline
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{SVM} & {ANN} & {SVM} & {ANN} \\ \hline

                    \end{tabular}
                \label{tablaResultadosIntrusos}
             % label: etiqueta tabla, sirve para ref. cruzadas, ver video: 
             % https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldU2mEWAeh4

                \end{center}
            \end{table}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code must start with `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hand-drawn sketch shows a four-column layout, while your code fragment indicates a layout with six or possibly even seven columns. The following code employs four columns, i.e., it adopts the hand-drawn layout.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float} % for 'H' float positioning parameter
\usepackage{array} % for '\extrarowheight' macro
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % optional -- for a more open "look"
    \caption{Aceptaciones a usuarios intrusos} 
    \label{tablaResultadosIntrusos}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}      
    \hline  
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Hiperparametros}}\\ 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{SVM} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ANN} \\ 
    \hline
    SVM & ANN & SVM & ANN \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}  
\end{document}
```